# Angular Animations: How to set transition timing dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm currently implementing Animations in an application and I face the problem that the timings for animation transitiions are stored in a json config file (I can't change that). There is a service that provides the values needed but since Angular Animations are declared in the @Component block I am not able to access the service.

```
transition('start => end', [animate(ConfigService.config.delay.firstDelay)])
```

This results as expected in an undefined error. I saw that one can build animations using the `AnimationBuilder` but it seems doing that way only provides the opportunity to provide simple animations without specific callbacks and multiple state transitions.

What would be the best approach to implement the transition timing in a dynamic way?

Comment: I'm afraid you need create the animations manually using AnimationBuilder: https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "manual Animations". the "translation" from a typical animation and a manual animation it's not difficult

In your component you defined

```
import {style,animate,AnimationBuilder,AnimationFactory,AnimationPlayer} from "@angular/animations";

 private player: AnimationPlayer;
 constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) {}
```

And create a function that "anime" an element, e.g.

```
/*I want "recreate" the animation
 transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('100ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('100ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))
  ])
*/
animate(element: any, state:string) {
    const myAnimation = state=='enter'?
       this.builder.build([
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          animate(this.timing, style({ opacity: 1 }))
       ]):
       this.builder.build([
        animate(this.timing, style({ opacity: 0 }))
     ])
     ;
    this.player = myAnimation.create(element);
    //you can control when the animation is finish
    this.player.onDone(()=>{
        this.toogle=!this.toogle;
    })
    this.player.play();
  }
```

So You can has, e.g.

```
<div #div style="background-color:red;width:5rem;height:5rem"></div>
<button (click)="animate(div,toogle?'enter':'leave');">click</button>
```

Or using ViewChild get an element and make the animation or call in ngOnInit or...

Comment: Do you know how to add the @trigger.done callback to an animation created using the AnimationBuilder? That would be crucial in order to display animations after the previous one finished. AnimationPlayer.play() takes no parameters for Callbacks. There is the Animation.Stop() function that seems to trigger the onDone Callback but the API does not mention how you set what function is called as a result.

Comment: I jsut updated the answer, is "control" the `this.player.onDone` before call to `player.play()`

Comment: I will implement it like this after my break and if it works I will mark your answer as accepted. I must have overlooked the onDone() function when I checked the documentation.